Creating separate lua tables for each object in an array
So I have an array of creatures from a game, each one is just the name as a string. I want to iterate over each one and create a table for each one that contains all of the creatures stats, hp, damage, etc. But I can't find a way to create new Lua tables, as assigning a new variable to a table doesn't copy it.
I really haven't tried much, as I'm pretty new to coding and have found near to no information online that deals with my specific issue.

You should really clarify what you mean by "But I can't find a way to create new Lua tables, as assigning a new variable to a table doesn't copy it.", preferably with a [mcve] (i.e., some code) to back it up.

you never search for something about your "specific issue". you need to abstract your problem, break it down into atomic steps before you do any research. you won't find the exact construction plans for your dream house online, but you will find all information on bricks, nails, concrete, ...

Poor choice of words there really, I searched for a lot of things around lua tables, defining objects, tables inside tables. And then I asked about my specific issue here.

Let's say your array looks like this (and keep in mind that lua arrays are tables with numeric indexes):
monsters = {[1] = "orc", [2] = "troll", [3] = "ogre"}

yeah, you'll get into trouble if you try to create a single "stats" table template and assign it to each monster name in the array:
stats = {["strength"] = 15, ["health"] = 10}

monster_stats = {} -- initialize new table for stats

for k,v in ipairs(monsters) do
        monster_stats[v] = stats
end

monster_stats["orc"].strength = 10 -- change strength

print(monster_stats["orc"].strength)

print(monster_stats["troll"].strength)

output:
10
10

We want to only change the orc's strength, but we end up changing everyone's strength. That's because both monster_stats["orc"] and monster_stats["troll"]
point at the same table in memory. What you want is a way to clone a table -- and there is an example at lua.org[0].
Add that function to the top of your script, and now you can call clone() during the assignment. Things work out as intended this time, because each monster's "stats" variable points to a different table in memory.
function clone (t)           -- t is a table
  local new_t = {}           -- create a new table
  local i, v = next(t, nil)  -- i is an index of t, v = t[i]
  while i do
    new_t[i] = v
    i, v = next(t, i)        -- get next index
  end
  return new_t
end
    
monsters = {[1] = "orc", [2] = "troll", [3] = "ogre"}

stats = {["strength"] = 15, ["health"] = 10}

monster_stats = {} -- initialize new table for stats

for k,v in ipairs(monsters) do
        monster_stats[v] = clone(stats)
end

monster_stats["orc"].strength = 10 -- change strength

print(monster_stats["orc"].strength)

print(monster_stats["troll"].strength)

output:
10
15

You can see that the tables are now all separate by printing out the values of the tables themselves:
print(monster_stats["orc"])
print(monster_stats["troll"])
print(monster_stats["ogre"])

output:
table: 0x55be070536b0
table: 0x55be07053bc0
table: 0x55be07053c80

References:
[0] https://www.lua.org/manual/2.4/node31.html

Okay that's almost exactly what I was looking for, my only question is that wouldn't the clone function only work once? Because after cloning it a second time it's just using the same table you defined as "new_t"? What I mean is if our original stats table is referred to as "monster_stats", and our clone is referred to as  "new_t", won't the second clone just be the second table? I apologize if that's a dumb question. Still wrapping my head around Lua tables.

@Gabriel - no such thing as a dumb question (en.wikipedia.org/wiki/No_such_thing_as_a_stupid_question). The answer is no, the clone function continues to create new tables every time it's called, thanks to the "local" keyword. I've edited my answer to demonstrate.

your clone function does not "clone" the table. it completely ignores a possible metatable.

Thanks! That clarifies what I was wondering about, thank you for explaining!
